# NULL fields document model

Tags: nosql, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and nosql document model in general.

In elasticsearch what is the best practice for fields that are null.

Should we declare it as null or leave it out completely?

Example:  the email field

```
[{
    id:1,
    name:"John",
    email:"userone@erj.com"
},
{
    id:2,
    name:"David",
    email:null
},
{
    id:3,
    name:"Tony"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do with the null field is completely up to you. By default, ES will completely ignore the null field. If you want, you can specify a default value in the mapping for the document for the null field as well.

mapping example:

```
{
    "_default_" : {
        "properties" : {
            "id" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            "name" : {"type" : "string"},
            "email" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "null_value" : "NOEMAILAVAILABLE"}
        }
    }
}
```

The potential ways to handle this are outlined here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types.html